# Test events were not received at the second run but 1st is OK. Check does not run test and later custom integrationTest task

Tags: java, gradle, junit, spock

Recently, I've decided to upgrade spring-boot to 3.1.2 and gradle 8.2.1, running java 19.
Unfortunately, `unbroken-dome.test-sets 4.0.0`, that I used for managing test modules, ceased to work, thus I decided to get rid of it and create similar in effect gradle script on my own.

The issue I'm having is that task `test` is once working and later returns `Test events were not received`, which is driving my crazy.

Other issue is with task `check`, ideally I'd like it to run `test` and my `integrationTest` task one after another but it seems it only runs `integrationTest`.

This is what I come up with (`test-suites.gradle`)

```
sourceSets {
  integrationTest {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
  }
}

configurations {
  integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
  integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testRuntime
  integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testCompileOnly
  integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testAnnotationProcessor
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  systemProperty 'spock.logEnabled', 'true'
  systemProperty 'spock.logFileDir', './build/test-results/test'
  systemProperty 'spock.logFileName', 'spock-report'
}

tasks.register('integrationTest', Test) {
  group = 'verification'

  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
  shouldRunAfter(test)

//  filter {
//    include '**/**IntegrationTest.class'
//    include '**/**IntegrationSpec.class'
//  }
}

check.dependsOn(integrationTest)
```

and my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.14.RELEASE'
  id 'org.flywaydb.flyway' version '9.21.0'
}

allprojects {

  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/')
    }
  }

  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'groovy'
  apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
  apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

  dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'

    testImplementation 'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.13'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.4-M1-groovy-4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.4-M1-groovy-4.0'
  }
}

apply from: file('gradle/test-suites.gradle')
apply from: file('gradle/database.gradle')

dependencies {
  implementation project(':my-service-backend-api')
  implementation project(':email-sender-service')
  implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.8'

  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

  implementation(group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.6.0')

  implementation(group: 'org.modelmapper', name: 'modelmapper', version: '3.1.1')
  implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.15.2'

  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'

  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:spock:1.18.3'
  testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.18.3'

}

project(':email-sender-service') {

  bootJar {
    enabled = false
  }

  dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.31'

  }
}

project(':my-service-backend-api') {
  bootJar {
    enabled = false
  }
}

group = 'pl.tchorzyksen'
version = '0.1.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'my-service-backend'
java {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_19
}
```

You can find the entire project here:
https://github.com/Tchorzyksen37/my-service-backend/tree/Create-integrationTest-module
The code is far from perfect and integrationTest are failing due to flyway not supporting the latest liquibase version.

I'd be happy to receive any help :D and thank you in advice for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use the official [jvm-test-suites](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) plugin. With that you can add additional test tasks without having to muck with all the wiring that was necessary previously.

This should get you started.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'jvm-test-suite'
}



testing {
    suites { 
        test { 
            useSpock('2.4-M1-groovy-4.0') 
        }

        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) { 
            useSpock('2.4-M1-groovy-4.0') 

            dependencies {
                // add dependencies for the integration test here and not in the top-level dependencies block

                implementation project() 
            }

            targets { 
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check') { 
    dependsOn(testing.suites.integrationTest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy does not re-run tests if source files are up to date. This being a root cause of my issue. To re-run test you can simply fiddle with test sources.

Comment: You can simple use `./gradlew integrationTest --rerun` which will rerun the given task, no need to modify any sources.